# Find regex pattern for following ,I have found this \w{3,6}\/\w{1,6}[\/\s\-]\w* but still not working

Tags: regex

Write a single generic regular expression which can extract the following patterns, given in (), from given sentences:

```
 a) Bridgestone Duravis M700 HD Tire LT265/75R16/10
                 (Extract : LT265/75R16/10)

 b) Michelin Energy MXV4 S8 Tire P215/55R17 93V                        (     
  (Extract : P215/55R17 93V)

 c) Bridgestone BLIZZAK DM-V2 Tire 235/55R18 (100T)                    (Extract : 235/55R18 )

 d) Goodyear Eagle F1 Asymmetric A/S 215/45ZR17/XL Tire 91W            (Extract : 215/45ZR17/XL)

 e) Bridgestone Blizzak DM-V1 Tire 275/60R18 113R BW                     (Extract : 275/60R18 113R BW)

 f) Continental ExtremeWinterContact Tire LT285/70R17/8 118Q BW           (Extract : LT285/70R17/8 118Q BW)

 g) MASTERCRAFT 285/70R17/E COURSER CXT OL TIRE                        (Extract : 285/70R17/E )

 h) Pirelli Night Dragon Motorcycle Front Tire 130/90-16 2211500           (Extract : 130/90-16 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\w*\d\w*\/\w+(?:[\/-]\w+)?(?:\s(?:\d+[A-Z]\w*|[A-Z]{1,2})\b)*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9idPK8/1

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use below code to achieve the required objective:


import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Extract {

//------------MAIN METHOD--------------------- 

 public static void main(String args[]){

 System.out.println("Extracted text ( ) : \n ");

try{
 File file = new File("C:/Users/Manjunath/Desktop/himanshu.txt");
 String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
 FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(absolutePath);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
 String line;

 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
 {
  stringBuffer.append(line);
  stringBuffer.append("\n");

  String mydata = line;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

  if (matcher.find())
  {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
  }

 fileReader.close();
  }

catch(IOException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}

//Regards,
From Manjunath
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use below code to achieve the required objective:


import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Extract {

//------------MAIN METHOD--------------------- 

 public static void main(String args[]){

 System.out.println("Extracted text ( ) : \n ");

try{
 File file = new File("C:/Users/Manjunath/Desktop/himanshu.txt");
 String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
 FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(absolutePath);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
 String line;

 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
 {
  stringBuffer.append(line);
  stringBuffer.append("\n");

  String mydata = line;
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

  if (matcher.find())
  {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
  }

 fileReader.close();
  }

catch(IOException e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}

//Regards,
From Manjunath
```